# Error in stored procedure for a tiny maintenance plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm getting an error when trying to create a stored procedure. I tried to figure it out but after going round for some time now, I decided to ask.

Here is the code for my SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_maintenance]

AS

begin

            dbcc checkdb('BD_Farmacia')

            GO
            ALTER INDEX ALL ON Artigo
            REBUILD
            GO

            GO
            ALTER INDEX ALL ON Categoria
            REBUILD
            GO

            GO
            ALTER INDEX ALL ON Composicao
            REBUILD
            GO

            GO
            ALTER INDEX ALL ON Iva
            REBUILD
            GO

            GO
            ALTER INDEX ALL ON Linha_venda
            REBUILD
            GO

            GO
            ALTER INDEX ALL ON Lote
            REBUILD
            GO

            GO
            ALTER INDEX ALL ON Utente
            REBUILD
            GO

            GO
            ALTER INDEX ALL ON Venda
            REBUILD
            GO


end
RETURN
```

Here's the error message:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_maintenance, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RETURN'.
```

Can someone help?
Thanks
Chiapa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have `GO` inside of a stored procedure - it is used to separate batches of SQL.

Comment: OK then, what should I do? What code must I remove/insert for this to work?

Comment: Remove all the 'GO' inside of SP. Also remove 'RETURN' a the end, you don't need it.